# Can't run npm script when headless emulator is running

Tags: android, macos, npm, android-emulator, command-line-tool

I'm running this scripts. but after the headless emulator command runs, then the npm script command never runs as the emulator command is running. how to fix that?

```
npm install
npm install -g appium
$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --list
$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64"
echo "no" | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name "Google_Pixel_Android_10" --device "pixel" --package "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64" --tag "google_apis" --abi "x86_64"
emulator -list-avds
emulator @Google_Pixel_Android_10 -no-audio -no-window -wipe-data
sleep 40
npm run android.app
```

Answer (score 0):

This command solved my issue. Posting it here if it helps anyone in future.

```
emulator @Google_Pixel_Android_10 -no-audio -no-window &
```